# Conda channels not being added from file

Tags: anaconda, conda

I have an environment file but for some reason it's not detecting the channels.

After activating, when I run `conda config --get channels` it returns nothing. When I run `conda info` I get:

```
channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
               https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

But it should contain the `conda-forge` and `bioconda` channels, since my `env.yml` file has them specified:

```
channels:
 - conda-forge
 - bioconda
 - defaults

dependencies:
 - r-base=3.5.1
 - python=3.7
 - rstudio=1.1.456
 - jupyter=1.0.0

#Python packages
 - pandas=0.24.2
 - scipy=1.2.1
 - numpy=1.16.4


#R packages
 - r-reticulate=1.12
```

Why are those 2 channels not detected? I noticed that it wasn't detecting the channels because if I run `conda install ipypublish` without specifying `-c conda-forge`, it won't install it. Or was I wrong in my assumption that specifying the channels in the `env.yml` file would make them available for installation too?

To note, I'm creating the environment by running `conda env create -f env.yml -p myenv-env`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the question is. Are you getting an error message for `conda env create...`?

Comment: @darthbith I should've made my question clearer. I've edited my post, hopefully it will be clear now

Comment: Adding channels in the `env.yml` file only applies to operations with that YAML file. It will not change the system configuration. If you want to do that, use `conda config --add channels <channel-name>`

Comment: I see! I thought it would tell the environment to search channels specifically from that point on. I guess this was a silly question after all...
Please feel free to write that as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding channels in the `env.yml` file only applies to operations with that YAML file. It will not change the system configuration. If you want to do that, use

```
conda config --add channels <channel-name>
```

to give the highest priority to a channel or

```
conda config --append channels <channel-name>
```

to give the lowest priority.